# Can i reduce the timeout of 6 minutes?

Tags: google-apps-script

apparently there is something in my code that is stuck as on occasions it causes the script to run until time out at 6minutes.

I am still trying to find that code but in the meantime, i really need to prevent the waiting. My script typically needs 10 seconds only.

Is there a way for me to set such that any script that hits 10 seconds should be terminated.

much appreciated!

Comment: It would probably be easier to turn the debugger on.

Comment: thanks. . but how do i track the errors when it happens when i am away. .   it appears to happen "randomly"  . .  so i cant be testing an execution but nothing goes wrong.

Comment: Check time  at various  parts of  the code and throw a error if `timestart-new Date()>10`

Comment: Share your code, we will help you come up with a better solution :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, isn't it better to rewrite the code so that it does not reach 6 minutes?

[Reference URL](https://officeforest.org/wp/2018/11/24/google-apps-script%E3%82%92%E9%AB%98%E9%80%9F%E5%8C%96%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8B%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81/)

If there is a possibility that it will exceed 6 minutes, try using a trigger to execute it for more than 6 minutes.

[Reference URL](https://officeforest.org/wp/2018/11/24/google-apps-script%E3%81%A75%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E5%A3%81%EF%BC%88%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A0%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%88%EF%BC%89%E3%82%92%E7%AA%81%E7%A0%B4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

Comment: hey thanks for this  i think you are getting me wrong.

my code finishes in less than 30 seconds.  however there is a bug somewhere that causes a hang until 6 minutes.

while i hunt for it, i need a way to PREVENT the script from running until 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple commands or is executed repeatedly, then TheMaster's recommendation in the comments is a good thing to be considered.

This will how it would look like.

```
function sampleFunction() {
  var startTime = Date.now();

  // do your thing, initialization, etc.

  while (true) {
    // do your thing, main process 

    // if 10 seconds is done
    if ((Date.now() - startTime) >= 10000)
      return;
  }
}
```

#### Limitations:

- If the command before the if condition checking the time takes 5 minutes, then you will be able to exit the script after that execution which will be 5 minutes later.
- You can't stop a single command mid-execution. You need to wait for your if condition to be executed.

#### Things to note:

- Exiting script through the method above works best when numerous lines of codes are being repeated in a loop and consistently checking the if condition so you can exit the script when the time comes.
- You can only exit the script in between commands, not during those commands. So using this between commands that take too much time might stop the script later than expected.
- It is still best to debug what is happening and why that "**BUG**"  happens, or maybe you missed something that is causing the unexpected behavior.

Upon providing the exact code, the community will be able to help you with a more specific answer. Until then, speculations could only be provided.